# phantomjs issue on mac with jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

I’m trying to experiment with some code I found at the repo

https://github.com/AlbanyCompSci/aeries-api

basically to help me login in to this grade portal called aeries and pull my kids high school grades.  But I keep getting errors related to “phantomjs”.  Also before it was throwing an error about chrome needing to be headless.

I’ve got some examples below where I’m loading the module from a local directory and I’ve added the some code to try to resolve the errors.  I’m running it on a mac in a jupyter notebook with python 3.6.  Any tips greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import Main as m
import Gradebooks as Gb
import GradebookDetails as GD
import Assignments as Ag
import AeriesSession as Ar


# below added to try to resolve phantomjs errors

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()

options.add_argument('headless')

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/Users/username/Desktop/Stuff/Aeries/api_version/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs.exe')
```

Warning:

```
/Users/username/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py:49: UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
  warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     75                                             stderr=self.log_file,
---> 76                                             stdin=PIPE)
     77         except TypeError:

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors)
    708                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 709                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    710         except:

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1343                             err_msg += ': ' + repr(err_filename)
-> 1344                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1345                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/username/Desktop/Stuff/Aeries/api_version/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs.exe': '/Users/username/Desktop/Stuff/Aeries/api_version/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-653e61cc9221> in <module>()
     14 options.add_argument('headless')
     15 
---> 16 driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/Users/username/Desktop/Stuff/Aeries/api_version/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs.exe')

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, desired_capabilities, service_args, service_log_path)
     54             service_args=service_args,
     55             log_path=service_log_path)
---> 56         self.service.start()
     57 
     58         try:

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     81                 raise WebDriverException(
     82                     "'%s' executable needs to be in PATH. %s" % (
---> 83                         os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
     84                 )
     85             elif err.errno == errno.EACCES:

WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Update:

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import Main as m
import Gradebooks as Gb
import GradebookDetails as GD
import Assignments as Ag
import AeriesSession as Ar
import os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()

options.add_argument('headless')


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath('/Users/username/Desktop/Stuff/Aeries/api_version/chromedriver'), chrome_options=chrome_options) 

driver.set_window_size(1120, 550) 
driver.get("duckduckgo.com/") 
driver.find_element_by_id('search_form_input_homepage').send_keys('realpython') 
driver.find_element_by_id('search_button_homepage').click() 
print(driver.current_url)
driver.quit()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-48f57c808807> in <module>()
     17 #downlod Chrome driver.exe
     18 
---> 19 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath('/Users/username/Desktop/Stuff/Aeries/api_version/chromedriver'), chrome_options=chrome_options)
     20 
     21 driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)

NameError: name 'chrome_options' is not defined
```

Comment: Phantomjs is deprecated now. You can use Chrome headless

Comment: @AnkurSingh Thank you for getting back to me so quickly.  I'm pretty new to this.  I'm running this in a cell in a jupyter notebook that's running on chrome.   I added all the "webdriver" stuff trying to fix the issue.  But is it something I need to do from terminal before I launch chrome?  Could you please tell me at a high level what phantomjs and chrome headless is doing?

Comment: Nothing you need to do ..from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('headless')
#downlod Chrome driver.exe 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath(“chromedriver"),   chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get("https://duckduckgo.com/")
driver.find_element_by_id('search_form_input_homepage').send_keys("realpython")
driver.find_element_by_id("search_button_homepage").click()
print driver.current_url

driver.quit()

Comment: Try above code.

Comment: @AnkurSingh Thank you again for all the help.  I added an update to the original post.  I downloaded chromedriver.exe and tried running the code you suggested.  Now I'm getting a name error for chrome_options.  Is there some mistake in my code?

Comment: @AnkurSingh I tried copying chromedriver into my /usr/local/bin and restarting my kernel, but I'm still getting the same Error: NameError: name 'chrome_options' is not defined

Comment: Options chrome_options = Options() options.add_argument('headless') #downlod Chrome driver.exe driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath(“chromedriver"), chrome_options=chrome_options)

Comment: Please try above code

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

...implies that the **phantomjs.exe** was not found in the specified location.

There seems to be a bit of messup as follows:

- ***PhantomJS Browser*** itself is a headless web browser scriptable with JavaScript which can run on *Windows*, *macOS*, *Linux*, and *FreeBSD*. So you don't need to explicitly pass the argument **headles** and you can remove it.
- You havn't mentioned about the underlying *Operating System*.

  - If you are on *Linux 64 bit OS* you need to download the `phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2` from [Download PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html), extract the binary and while mentioning the absolute path of the **phantomjs** binary you need to strip off the extension part (i.e. `.exe`)
  - If you are on *Linux 32 bit OS* you need to download the `phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-i686.tar.bz2` from [Download PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) , extract the binary and while mentioning the absolute path of the **phantomjs** binary you need to strip off the extension part (i.e. `.exe`)
  - If you are on *Mac OS X* you need to download the `phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx.zip` from [Download PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) , extract the binary and while mentioning the absolute path of the **phantomjs** binary you need to strip off the extension part (i.e. `.exe`)
  - If you are on *Windows OS* you need to download the `phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2` from [Download PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) , extract the binary and while mentioning the path of the **phantomjs** binary you need to provide the absolute path including the extension (i.e. `phantomjs.exe`)
- Though you observe the *deprecation notice* but the support is still there. So for the time being you can ignore the error:

  ```
  C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py:49: UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
    warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '
  ```
- On *Windows8* system here is the working code:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
  print(driver.title)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py:49: UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
    warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '
  Google
  ```