# selenium ElementNotVisibleException in password_elem

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have the code below where I’m trying to launch chrome, go to a website, and login.  This is based off of code I found in the repo below:

https://github.com/AlbanyCompSci/aeries-api
basically it’s to help me login in to this grade portal called aeries and pull my kids high school grades. 
I was getting errors related to “phantomjs”.  Also before it was throwing an error about chrome needing to be headless.  I got help with that in an earlier post:
[phantomjs issue on mac with jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52751516/phantomjs-issue-on-mac-with-jupyter-notebook/52754202#52754202)
which suggested using chromedriver instead of phantomjs.
Now instead of loading the modules from the repo, as I had in the previous post, I’m using pieces of the code from the repo and trying to step through them and understand how they work.
 I’m running it on a mac in a jupyter notebook with python 3.6. Any tips greatly appreciated.
When I run the code below I get an “ElementNotVisibleException” error related to the “password_elem.send_keys(password)” part of the code.  Does anyone know what might be causing that issue and can you suggest how to resolve it?  I’m new to selenium so any tips are greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

Options

options = Options()

chrome_options = Options() 
options.add_argument('headless') #downlod Chrome driver.exe 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("chromedriver"), chrome_options=chrome_options)


#system
#JSON for language agnostic output
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json


# trying to recreate getGradebooks
# Gradebooks.getGradebooks(session)

#re allows for matching text with regular expressions (including through BeautifulSoup)
#dateutil.parser provies .parse() to convert plain text dates in a variety of formats into datetime objects
import re, dateutil.parser
#BeautifulSoup provide a model for the source HTML
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#The default address of the gradebook page for AUSDK12 Aeries
# Drew Gradebook page
ADDRESS = 'https://abip.fsusd.org/ParentPortal/GradebookSummary.aspx'


# recreate session = AeriesSession.Session(email, password)

#Webdriver is interface to the selected browser (PhantomJS)
from selenium import webdriver
#Ability to select values in HTML <select> tags
from selenium.webdriver.support import select
import time

#Base URL of the AUSDK12 Aeries system
BASE_URL=   'https://abip.fsusd.org/ParentPortal/'
#'https://abi.ausdk12.org/aeriesportal/'
#Name of the login page (relative to the base URL)
LOGIN_PAGE =    'LoginParent.aspx'
#<form> id, not currently used
#FORM_ID =      'form1'
#id for email <input>
EMAIL_ID =      'portalAccountUsername'
#id for password <input>
PASSWORD_ID =   'portalAccountPassword'
#id for login button
LOGIN_ID =      'LoginButton'


email=‘madeup@madeup.com’
password=‘madeup’


login_url = BASE_URL + LOGIN_PAGE
#driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_log_path='/dev/null')
driver.get(login_url)
email_elem = driver.find_element_by_id(EMAIL_ID)
email_elem.send_keys(email)
password_elem = driver.find_element_by_id(PASSWORD_ID)
password_elem.send_keys(password)
login_elem = driver.find_element_by_id(LOGIN_ID)
login_elem.click()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ElementNotVisibleException                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-b6872465bdd4> in <module>()
      6 email_elem.send_keys(email)
      7 password_elem = driver.find_element_by_id(PASSWORD_ID)
----> 8 password_elem.send_keys(password)
      9 login_elem = driver.find_element_by_id(LOGIN_ID)
     10 login_elem.click()

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in send_keys(self, *value)
    477         self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
    478                       {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
--> 479                        'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
    480 
    481     # RenderedWebElement Items

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    626             params = {}
    627         params['id'] = self._id
--> 628         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    629 
    630     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    318         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    319         if response:
--> 320             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    321             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    322                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591059 (a3d9684d10d61aa0c45f6723b327283be1ebaad8),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the next button after typing the email.

> ```
> email_elem = driver.find_element_by_id(EMAIL_ID)
> email_elem.send_keys(email)
>
> driver.find_element_by_id('next').click() // you are missing this
>
> password_elem = driver.find_element_by_id(PASSWORD_ID)
> password_elem.send_keys(password)
> login_elem = driver.find_element_by_id(LOGIN_ID)
> login_elem.click()
> ```